# Connecting a Silicon Temperature sensor to MCU

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, temperature

I have a project where I need to connect a [Phillips KTY83-1 Temperature sensor](http://www1.fs.cvut.cz/cz/U12110/TEM/senzory/KTY83.pdf) to an MCU to measure temperature. It appears that as temperature changes, the resistance of the device changes. I am wondering if the circuit to connect it to the MCU (TI MSP430F5529) is as simple as a voltage divider, and size it to +3.3V to 0V? There is a minimum current requirement of 1mA, so do you just size the resistors so that in the worst case you get 1mA through?

Also, how would I protect the input from the outside world if I want to be able to remove and attach the probe at will. Will a Zener Diode selected to just over VCC do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company is now called NXP and has a number of useful datasheets and [application notes](http://www.nxp.com/documents/other/SC17_GENERAL_TEMP_1996_3.pdf).

A typical readout circuit is shown below. 
[image]

Of course a simple voltage divider could be used as well, if the input impedance of the ADC is high enough. The linearization could be done in software.
[image]

The two examples are taken from the AN.